# GitHub Actions: every step must define a `uses` or `run` key

Tags: github-actions

I would like to set up github action which

- calls nuget and caches it
- builds solution
- runs unit tests

I managed to get the second and third step is working but it's now a problem to combine following first step.

```yaml
 - name: Cache Nuget
    - uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ~/.nuget/packages
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/*.csproj') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-
```

I tried to put that after `- uses: actions/checkout@v2` but It throws following error.

```
every step must define a `uses` or `run` key
```

```
   ...
   steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Cache Nuget
    - uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ~/.nuget/packages
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/*.csproj') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

*Here's the full config.*

```yaml
name: Build and Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Cache Nuget
    - uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ~/.nuget/packages
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/*.csproj') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Run Tests
      run: dotnet test --configuration Release --no-build --verbosity minimal /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=TestResults/ /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov
    - name: Publish coverage report to coveralls.io   
      uses: coverallsapp/github-action@master   
      with:
       github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
       path-to-lcov: Tests/App.Tests/TestResults/coverage.info
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your formatting is off. Use the dash only on the first line, like so:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Cache Nuget
  uses: actions/cache@v1
```

If you also prefix the last line with a dash (`-`), then GitHub thinks the `name` is a separate step and it doesn't know what to do with it. Not using a dash, however, means the `uses` belongs to the same step as `name`.

Comment: In my case is because I've using `- working-directory: bin` with a dash. It need to be added after the run command and without dash. Hope it help others.